# Get IP from Citrix Host in ASP.NET MVC WebApp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, ip, host, citrix

I have a ASP.NET MVC WebApp which is called from clients running in a Citrix Environment.
Is it possible to detect the IP address of the Citrix Server (where the Client is executed) 
from the http request?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your client IP address should be available regardless it's location on Citrix Server. Have you tried

```
string ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
```

or

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;
```

Or your Citrix machine is behind some proxy server? In this case try:

```
string ip = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
```

And if the question is about IP address of a physical host that XenApp virtual machine is ruining on, then it may may be impossible to know it from a request. Physical network may be completely independent from virtual one and client's request will never go through it. So you need another API (XenServer or other virtualizing system) to match VM address to a physical host address.

Comment: ... this will return the address of the virtual client.

But what I need the the address of the host where the virtual client is running on.
I have the same problem when I execute a virtual machine with a bridged network.

For better understanding:
some properties of my website have to depend on the physical machine, not on the virtual client.

Comment: Do you mean that your XenApp server is running on XenServer host and you need to get this host IP out of the request that came from published browser?

Comment: ... yes I think this describes the situation well. The browser is running on a virtual Desktop but I need to identify the host.

Comment: See updated answer. I think this is possible only using another API